# Why is my observable array losing values?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout v3.2 and I'm having problems with observable array.

I'm creating an observable array

```
self.relatorioDataSources = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Then, I'm trying to add an array to this observable array.
Below the image (get from chrome developer tools) of my array:

[image: Array of object before add to observable array]

Then I add this to my observable array with the following command:

```
//self.relatorioDataSources is my empty observable array
self.relatorioDataSources(item.relatorioDataSources);
```

Then, my observable array, and my common array, loses the idDataSource value:

[image: Observable array and array after add values to observable array]

Comment: can you put together a minimal working example that demonstrates this, like on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `observableArray value` so you want to push a new element to like this `self.relatorioDataSources.push(novoDataSource)`, and the data sources doesn't have id because any item of `item.relatorioDataSources` haven't.

Comment: they are overwriting the existing array, but the data shown does have the idDataSource field set to an actual value (86). There's some other data manipulation happening, which is why we need a fiddle demonstrating this

Comment: i agree, but just to explain what happens

Comment: so you agree that your answer doesn't fit the problem, but you just wanted to throw something out there? please.

Comment: That isn't the goal here man, what i put in my answer is to he gets the idea about what happening, here isn't something like _coders clan_ .